# ng-options with objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select

I have an Object like this

```
var obj = {"id":143,
           "chance":5,
            "name" : "super"};
```

now I want to render `selectbox` with `ng-options` using above `object`.

I tried this:

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="id as name for (id,name) in obj"></select>
```

but its not Working.

Any help.

Thanks

Comment: The only that I saw is the </selecct> as close tag.

Comment: NO its a typo. wrote correct in my code

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `ng-options` is made to iterate over a key/value object or directly over an Array.

Therefore, I would either rewrite your object to an array:

```
var objects = [{"id":143, "chance":5, "name" : "super"}];

<select ng-model="value" ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in objects"></select>
```

Or change it to be a key/value object:

```
var objects = {"143": {"chance":5, "name" : "super"}};

<select ng-model="value" ng-options="id as obj.name for (id, obj) in objects"></select>
```